# Springer journal status from "Editor Invited" to "Editor Assignment Pending"

Tags: journals, paper-submission

The status for a paper that I have submitted to a Springer journal was "Editor Invited". Now it is "Editor Assignment Pending".

What does it mean really? It means that the invited editor desk rejected the paper (or did not want to handle it)?

Comment: It could mean anything. You will know when you get an email by the journal informing you about their decision. The best thing you can do before that is *not* to check the status of your paper. What good does that do? What action can you take based on that information? Nothing. You did the best you could when you submitted your article, now it is completely out of your hands. Any second you waste on looking up the status, is a second you did not spent writing your next paper, or cooking for a loved own, or relax, or do something else worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not a rejection If the editor rejected it, you would have gotten a rejection letter, not gone back to the "editor assignment" phase. Rather, probably the journal assigned an editor to your submission, but the editor did not want to handle it (because e.g., the editor's workload was too heavy, the editor has an ongoing medical or family emergency, or the editor felt another editor would be better equipped to handle your paper). The journal is probably in the process of finding another editor for your submission.

I would suggest not worrying about it at this stage. The following question is related and useful

[What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a)